# Extracting Number from Log Lines

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to extract a number from a live log file using Regex in Powershell. My regex code works in the sense that it will only return a number to the left of the letter A but for some reason it returns the entire line instead of the isolated number.

I'm trying to convert a log file from:

```
1/11/2016 3:26:12 PM 1/11/2016 3:27:00 PM 86.4 A
1/11/2016 3:26:12 PM 1/11/2016 3:28:00 PM 86.3 A
1/11/2016 3:26:12 PM 1/11/2016 3:29:00 PM 86.8 A
1/11/2016 3:26:12 PM 1/11/2016 3:29:16 PM 86.7 A
```

To:

```
86.4
86.3
86.8
86.7
```

Here's my code so far:

```
$DATAPath = "C:\Code\DATA.txt"
$regex = '.*\d\s+A'

Get-Content -Path $DATAPath -Tail 1 -Wait |
    Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches
```

Comment: Use [`\d+\.\d+\s*A`](https://regex101.com/r/nV6tQ6/1)

Comment: `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s+A)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex itself is a bit quirky `.*\d\s+A` means: "anything goes, then a single digit, then at least one wihtespace and finally letter A". This covers more cases than you are interested in. It will match, say, line that contains only four characters like "94.9 A".

Depending on the log file structure and false positives, more strict approach and/or grouping is helpful. Like so, `(?:PM\s+)(\d+\.\d+)(?:\s+A)`

```
(?:PM\s+)   := match letters PM followed with at least one whitespace
(\d+\.\d+)  := match at least one digit followed by dot and at least one digit
(?:\s+A)    := match at least one whitespace followed by letter A
```

As for an example,

```
[regex]$regex = '(?:PM\s+)(\d+\.\d+)(?:\s+A)'

$s = @("1/11/2016 3:26:12 PM 1/11/2016 3:27:00 PM 86.4 A",
"1/11/2016 3:26:12 PM 1/11/2016 3:28:00 PM 86.3 A",
"1/11/2016 3:26:12 PM 1/11/2016 3:29:00 PM 86.8 A",
"1/11/2016 3:26:12 PM 1/11/2016 3:29:16 PM 86.7 A",
"foobarline shouldn't match",
"94.9 A",
"PM 84.8 A")

# Note that the two invalid rows are skipped
$s | % { $regex.Matches($_) | % {$_.groups[1].value} }
86.4
86.3
86.8
86.7
84.8
```

Comment: Quirky is a bit of an understatement ! Thank you for breaking down my regex code and adding some extra examples. I'm totally new to .NET language programming but this helped a ton!